# How to post an album to a fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I admin a fan page.

One of the fans created a photo album on his own page.
I want to post it on the fan page, but in the album all have is "post the album to profile", and if I do it I get it in my own profile, not on the fan page.

Any idea how to post the album to the fan page ?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Facebook's new 'Login as Page' feature under the 'Account'. When you select it you will be logged into Facebook as the Page. From there you can use the "post the album to profile" link and it will post to the Pages profile instead of your personal one.